# Is there a way to call the OPC complaince test tool using python?

Tags: python, opc-ua, opc

As CTT is a windows application , I couldn't find a way to make api calls to it , is there a way to open and run it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation for the CTT, you'll see it has a CLI that allows it to be run as part of a (Windows-based) build/CI environment.